# Passing a javascript value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to pass a numeric value through to the following Javascript function.

```
function swap2() {
var oldDiv = document.getElementById("product-grid");
var newDiv = document.getElementById("product-page");
oldDiv.style.display = "none";
newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

I want to be able to call the function with a number in the bracket like...

```
onclick="swap2(2)"
```

And then have the newDiv variable change based on that number like so...

```
 var newDiv = document.getElementById("product-page2");
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function(variable){
    // process using 'variable'
}
```

that's how you pass a variable to a function. Thus:

```
function swap2(n) {
    var oldDiv = document.getElementById("product-grid");
    var newDiv = document.getElementById("product-page" + n);
    oldDiv.style.display = "none";
    newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```